# How do I download a folder in ftp mode from the terminal?

Tags: ftp

Using the `get` command from the terminal in ftp mode, I can download a single file. Which command should I use in order to download a complete folder containing many files in ftp mode?

Comment: There is a video [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vLjPUHjvME) showing you how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mget`

To copy multiple files from the remote machine to the local machine; You are prompted for a y/n answer before transferring each file

And if you type `prompt` first as a command it will not ask for y/n each file.

Something like this:

```
binary
prompt
mget *
```

Answer (score 5):

For this action I use lftp.

```
sudo apt-get install lftp
```

Make ftp connection

```
lftp -u username server_ip_address
```

You will be asked for password.
After login to server you can `ls` or `dir` to see folder/files

To get folder with all subfolder and files

```
mirror folder_name
```

All will be on you PC.